# Declare a subclass with a complete definition

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am trying to do the following:

```
-- enum which wraps arround
class (Enum a, Bounded a) => CyclicEnum a where
    next, prev :: a -> a

-- for equatable types this is readily implemented
instance (Enum a, Bounded a, Eq a) => CyclicEnum a where
    next x | x == maxBound = minBound
           | otherwise     = succ x

    prev x | x == minBound = maxBound
           | otherwise     = pred x
```

But this doesn't compile unless I enable both FlexibleInstances and UndecidableInstances, which doesn't seem right. What is the proper way (i.e., the generally used approach, preferably without language extensions) to do something like this? Is there one?

Comment: You could always provide an instance for a wrapping newtype.

Comment: But then I'd have to do that for every type which is both Enum and Bounded. What I want to say is 'all types which are both Enum and Bounded are also Cyclic, and in this way: ...'.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I think that would qualify as the "generally used approach" - to clarify for the OP, maybe something like `newtype CyclicGroup a = CyclicGroup a; instance (Enum a, Bounded a, Eq a) => CyclicEnum (CyclicGroup a) where ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, there is nothing wrong at all with `FlexibleInstances` – it just disables a few restrictions of standard Haskell that are mostly there for historical reasons and perhaps for making compilers easier to write. But if you only use GHC – as almost everybody does – then there's no real reason not to use `FlexibleInstances`.

`UndecidableInstances` is more debatable, but there are some cases where it's definitely ok to use that too.

However, in your example, I don't see the need to define any new type class at all! Why not just define, as free functions,

```
next, prev :: (Enum a, Bounded a, Eq a) => a -> a
next x | x == maxBound = minBound
       | otherwise     = succ x
prev x | x == minBound = maxBound
       | otherwise     = pred x
```

Well. Probably your intention was to also add other instances for `CyclicEnum`, apart from the generic one. But that's actually not possible! Even with `UndecidableInstances`. It needs `OverlappingInstances` (or rather, `Overlappable` pragmas), but overlapping instances are *really* not something you should use just because you can.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! I'm an idiot! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Note that if you want you can define a synonym called `CyclicEnum` for this constraint like so `type CyclicEnum a = (Enum a, Bounded a, Eq a)` simply for readability. Actually, if you're clever, you don't need the Eq, since Enum gives you an induced order, but that is besides the point.

Comment: @user2407038 How do I rewrite the definition of next and prev so that it doesn't need Eq?

Comment: @JSQuareD: instead of `x==maxBound` you write `fromEnum x == fromEnum (maxBound :: a)`, but I wouldn't necessarily consider that a good idea.

Comment: @user2407038 right, though `type CyclicEnum = ...` requires `ConstraintKinds`. Now, that's also an extension which is completely fine in itself, but since it's still so new it's not quite as accepted yet. Many people still have GHC < 7.4, alas...

Comment: I guess there could be problems if the particular `Enum` was larger than `Int`? And if you really would like to avoid constraint kinds, you can write `class (Enum a, Bounded a, Eq a) => CyclicEnum a; instance (Enum a, Bounded a, Eq a) => CyclicEnum a` which only requires flexible instances which I think is a more established and commonly used extension, but at this point I am just splitting hairs.. although the 2nd version does have the distinct advantage of giving you an type class that you can partially apply, if such a thing interests you.

Comment: @user2407038: this is already extensions overkill here, but I'll throw in `LiberalTypeSynonyms`, which allows partial application of `type` constraints under some circumstances!

Comment: Edward Kmett takes the opposing view. He thinks `FlexibleInstances` can be trouble but doesn't fear `UndecidableInstances` at all. In this particular case, I don't think either is the least bit problematic.

Comment: The trouble with using a synonym is that type synonyms, even with `LiberalTypeSynonyms`, are decidedly second-class. People using your synonym will be limited in possibly surprising ways.

Comment: @dfeuer I'd be interested to read what the objections are to `FlexibleInstances`. I tried to google it but didn't get far because there are so many other mentions of it. Any pointers on where you might have read that?

Comment: @DougMcClean, I don't have references; he told me in person. The issue is that `FlexibleInstances` allows the creation of instances that can cause the instance resolution mechanism to get stuck. Unfortunately, I can't give you a really general example off the top of my head, but certainly I can say that using an equality constraint leads to much better instance resolution than (flexibly) doubling a type variable. The particular case of `instance ... => C a` reduces immediately to the constraints, so it should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [default signatures](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html) to get what you asked for: a default implementation for equatable types only (though @leftaroundabout's answer may be better for this specific case).

```
class (Enum a, Bounded a) => CyclicEnum a where
    next, prev :: a -> a
    default next, prev :: Eq a => a -> a

    next x | x == maxBound = minBound
           | otherwise     = succ x

    prev x | x == minBound = maxBound
           | otherwise     = pred x
```

Comment: Wouldn't I then still have to define a bunch of instances?

Comment: @JSQuareD Oops, you are right. This just allows you to make them empty.